# Login With Facebook on Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to add 'Login With Facebook' Feature to my app and I'm facing the following Issues

1. When I add Facebook Login button to XML, I get rendering issues(which goes away when I refresh the Layout, but again there appears a White screen like Below)
   Code:
   `<TextView
       android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="31dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
       android:text="Login With Facebook"
       android:backgroundTint="#948b8b" />
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
       android:id="@+id/loginButton"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>`

[Screen Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi3No.png)

2. When I try to Run my App, I get the below Stack Trace in Console.

I'm all new to Android and Couldn't solve the issues. Your Help is much appreciated.
Code:

`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        if(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(LoginActivity.this) != null){
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }`

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                        Process: com.example.batman.eventmanager, PID: 2111                                                                             java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)                                                                                   at com.example.batman.eventmanager.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:33)                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)                                                                                Caused by: null                                                                                   at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)                                                                                   at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:735)                                                                                   at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)                                                                                   at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)                                                                                    at com.example.batman.eventmanager.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:33)                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

3. Below is my Manifest XML
   `

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".LoginActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.batman.eventmanager.MainActivity" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

   <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
       android:configChanges=
           "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
       android:label="@string/app_name" />
   ```

   `
   TIA

Comment: why you set android:visibility="gone" to login button

Comment: Because I'm using the TextView as a button and don't want the Facebook button widget to lie around in the screen

Comment: Look for edit of my answer, may be it will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the Facebook sdk before ***setContentView()***

put below code before setContentView();

```
       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
       callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` at `java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)`  shows that you didn't initialize the facebook SDK.  Do the following to resolve this exception.

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    LoginFragment loginFragment;      

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                    loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(android.R.id.content, loginFragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {

                    loginFragment = (LoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
                }
            }
```

After that take a new fragment LoginFragment and add all the functionality here:

```
public class LoginFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_about_me");
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);

          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FaceBook SDK to enable facebook login. The developer portal of facebook has all the details you are looking for. Please spend time understanding the steps.

Details at, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android